# Adobe XFDF Format

Tags: adobe, fdf

How popular is Adobe's XFDF format? An application that I support at work is using XFDF to populate data in pdf documents. I saw a bunch of xml formats [here](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/xml/index_arch.html).

Shall I consider switching to some of the newer xml formats mentioned?

Do you know if XFDF format is going to be supported by Adobe in long-term?

Answer (score 0):

adobe xfdf is still supported 4 years later.. so your answer is YES :)